# Не работает --more-- для вывода под категорий в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть код, он по ид категории выводит все под категории.

```
$parent_id = id;
$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
  'child_of' => $parent_id,
  'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ) {
  foreach ($sub_cats as $item) {
    $rez .= '
    <div>
      '.strip_tags($item->description).'
    </div>
    ';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем глобальную переменную пост
}
```

Все работает, встала задача обрезать текст и обрезать его стандартным wp тегом `--more--`, данный код выводит полный текст под категории.

Как правильно реализовать вывод под категорий с рабочим тегом `--more--`?

Comment: Не пытайтесь прикрутить весло к телеге. "Стандартный" тег more работает только с контентом поста. К описанию категории он не имеет никакого отношения. Вам надо программно обрезать длину описания подкатегории.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Понял, спасибо, просто в редакторе у категории был тег ‘more’ я думал он и к категориям относится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом

```
$parent_id = id;
$sub_cats = get_categories( array(
  'child_of' => $parent_id,
  'hide_empty' => 0
) );
if( $sub_cats ) {
  foreach ($sub_cats as $item) {
    list($description_start, $description_end) = explode('<!--more-->', $item->description);// Разбиваем текст на две части, разделитель <!--more-->
    $rez .= '
    <div>
      '.strip_tags($description_start).'
    </div>
    ';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata(); // сбрасываем глобальную переменную пост
}
```